# why my image upload doesnt work?

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading

I know my question isn't new but I don't know why it is not working.

In my controller, If is false and my
 image doesn't upload and the data of image don't save in database and  else is execute.

```
<form name="f" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/aparteman/save" role="form">
<!--<input type="text" name="gh" id="gh"></input>-->
<input type="hidden" name="g" id="g" value=<?php echo $insert_id; ?>></input>

<div class="col-md-1"></div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<span class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$(this).parent().find('input[type=file]').click();">
<span class="glyphicon-class glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>&nbsp;Browse</span>
<input onchange="$(this).parent().parent().find('.form-control').html($(this).val().split(/[\\|/]/).pop());" style="display: none; width:50%;" type="file" name="Name1" id="Name1"></input>
</span>
</form>
```

**mycontroller**

```
public function save()
{               
    $config['upload_path']='/upload/';
    $config['allowed_types']= 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['max_size']= 2000;
    $config['max_width']= 1024;
    $config['max_height']= 768;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if ($this->upload->do_upload('Name1'))
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $my_data['photo']=$data['upload_data']['file_name'];
        $my_data = array(
        'FIDKhane' => $this->input->post('g')
                    );
        $this->load->model('apartemanmodel');
        $this->apartemanmodel->insert_images($my_data);
    }           

    else {
        echo "...";            
    }
```

**my model**

```
  function insert_images($my_data)
  { 
    $this->db->set('Name1',$my_data['photo']);
    $this->db->set('FIDKhane',$my_data['FIDKhane']);
    $this->db->insert('imagekhane');    
 }
```

Thanks for your helping.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have overwrite your variable `$my_data`. Try to use this code instead:

```
$my_data = array(
  'photo' => $data['upload_data']['file_name'],
  'FIDKhane' => $this->input->post('g')
);
```

Comment: if ($this->upload->do_upload('Name1'))                                                                this if cant execute because its false....

Comment: You don't need to initialize upload after loading library

Comment: Try to display errors by adding: 
`if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error); 
}`

Comment: The upload path does not appear to be valid.  show this error my upload folder is next to the application in my ci.

Comment: if your upload path is not valid maybe you wanted to use `$config['upload_path']='./upload/';` ?